# Why don't property lists use more XML-element types?

Tags: preferences, plist, xml

Most software would store information in XML rather like this:

```xml
<book>
  <title>Generic Examples, the Internet, and You</title>
  <length pages="43" />
  <authors>
    <person>Yolanda Squatpump</person>
    <collective>
      Anonymous 1
      Anonymous 2
      <et.al />
    </collective>
  </authors>
</book>
```

Whereas Apple's `.plist`s would resemble:

```xml
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>book</string>
  <key>title</key>
  <string>Generic Examples, the Internet, and You</string>
  <key>length</key>
  <dict>
    <key>pages</key>
    <integer>43</integer>
  </dict>
  <key>authors</key>
  <dict>
    <key>person</key>
    <string>Yolanda Squatpump</string>
    <key>collective</key>
    <array>
      <string>Anonymous 1</string>
      <string>Anonymous 2</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

## Why?

Comment: As written, this invites people to offer any idea why the designers chose to pick a certain style and lacks a clear problem you are trying to solve (other than wanting a discussion on this). Would you have a crack at editing this per the [faq] guidelines or ask on [meta] for help before flagging this to be reopened? There could be a good underlying question, but I can't guess it to edit it in as written.

Comment: The XML format is based on the [old-style](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/PropertyLists/OldStylePlists/OldStylePLists.html) format that only supports NSString, NSData, NSArray, and NSDictionary.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine the primary reason is that property lists are designed to be easily accessed by Objective-C programs. Every iOS and OS X program at a minimum uses a property list for communicating basic information about itself to the system, and most use them frequently in their code, particularly for storing preferences (this is why most apps settings are accessible via the `defaults` command).

Property lists in Obj-C are defined as a dictionary type that contains *only* strings, numbers, arrays, dates, raw bytes and other dictionaries. Prescribing exactly what types a property list can contain means you can access any one and know what to expect. Allowing more free-form XML elements would increase complexity and require a lot of reworking existing code, for not much benefit.